# My SVG source code is not working in html <code> tags

Tags: html, svg, frontend

I need to add my embaded SVG source code to one of my websites. Example below,

[image]

This way user can copy the original svg code of my icons. I've tried to add it but it didn't appear as in the picture rather it gave me the icon instead -
This is the code I have tired

```
            <pre ><code class="language-html" data-lang="html">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="5rem" height="5rem" fill="none"><defs/><g filter="url(#filter0_ddd)"><rect width="38" height="40" x="8" y="4" fill="#fff" rx="5"/></g><g filter="url(#filter1_ddd)"><path fill="#78A0FF" d="M14 11.2c0-1.21503.985-2.2 2.2-2.2h22.6c1.215 0 2.2.98497 2.2 2.2v2.6c0 1.215-.985 2.2-2.2 2.2H16.2c-1.215 0-2.2-.985-2.2-2.2v-2.6z"/></g><g filter="url(#filter2_ddd)"><path fill="#78A0FF" d="M14 22.2c0-1.215.985-2.2 2.2-2.2h22.6c1.215 0 2.2.985 2.2 2.2v14.6c0 1.215-.985 2.2-2.2 2.2H16.2c-1.215 0-2.2-.985-2.2-2.2V22.2z"/></g><defs><filter id="filter0_ddd" width="54" height="56" x="0" y="0" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/><feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/><feOffset/><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation=".5"/><feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.04 0"/><feBlend in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/><feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/><feOffset/><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1"/><feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0.992157 0 0 0 0 0.976471 0 0 0 0.12 0"/><feBlend in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="effect2_dropShadow"/><feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/><feOffset dy="4"/><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4"/><feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0.992157 0 0 0 0 0.976471 0 0 0 0.18 0"/><feBlend in2="effect2_dropShadow" result="effect3_dropShadow"/><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect3_dropShadow" result="shape"/></filter><filter id="filter1_ddd" width="43" height="23" x="6" y="5" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/><feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/><feOffset/><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation=".5"/><feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.04 0"/><feBlend in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/><feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/><feOffset/><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1"/><feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.470833 0 0 0 0 0.626471 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0.12 0"/><feBlend in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="effect2_dropShadow"/><feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/><feOffset dy="4"/><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4"/><feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.470833 0 0 0 0 0.626471 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0.18 0"/><feBlend in2="effect2_dropShadow" result="effect3_dropShadow"/><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect3_dropShadow" result="shape"/></filter><filter id="filter2_ddd" width="43" height="35" x="6" y="16" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/><feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/><feOffset/><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation=".5"/><feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.04 0"/><feBlend in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/><feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/><feOffset/><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1"/><feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.470833 0 0 0 0 0.626471 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0.12 0"/><feBlend in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="effect2_dropShadow"/><feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/><feOffset dy="4"/><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4"/><feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.470833 0 0 0 0 0.626471 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0.18 0"/><feBlend in2="effect2_dropShadow" result="effect3_dropShadow"/><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect3_dropShadow" result="shape"/></filter></defs></svg>
            </code></pre>
```

So, I've fetched the bootstrap SVG's source code to see how they have done it. And I've found their SVG source code is different than mine. Maybe somehow, they have converted it to show the SVG code in the website.

```
          <pre class="chroma"><code class="language-html" data-lang="html"><span class="p">&lt;</span><span class="nt">svg</span> <span class="na">width</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">"1em"</span> <span class="na">height</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">"1em"</span> <span class="na">viewBox</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">"0 0 16 16"</span> <span class="na">class</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">"bi bi-bell"</span> <span class="na">fill</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">"currentColor"</span> <span class="na">xmlns</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"</span><span class="p">&gt;</span>
            <span class="p">&lt;</span><span class="nt">path</span> <span class="na">d</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">"M8 16a2 2 0 0 0 2-2H6a2 2 0 0 0 2 2z"</span><span class="p">/&gt;</span>
            <span class="p">&lt;</span><span class="nt">path</span> <span class="na">fill-rule</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">"evenodd"</span> <span class="na">d</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s">"M8 1.918l-.797.161A4.002 4.002 0 0 0 4 6c0 .628-.134 2.197-.459 3.742-.16.767-.376 1.566-.663 2.258h10.244c-.287-.692-.502-1.49-.663-2.258C12.134 8.197 12 6.628 12 6a4.002 4.002 0 0 0-3.203-3.92L8 1.917zM14.22 12c.223.447.481.801.78 1H1c.299-.199.557-.553.78-1C2.68 10.2 3 6.88 3 6c0-2.42 1.72-4.44 4.005-4.901a1 1 0 1 1 1.99 0A5.002 5.002 0 0 1 13 6c0 .88.32 4.2 1.22 6z"</span><span class="p">/&gt;</span>
          <span class="p">&lt;/</span><span class="nt">svg</span><span class="p">&gt;</span></code></pre>
```

You would notice they are using span tags a lot. May I know How I can convert my SVG code to something similar like bootstraps SVG source code to show it in my website as the first sample.

Answer (score 0):

Few lines of `javascript` is required in order to make the copy to clipboard `button` workable
Also I have replace your `pre` tag with `xmp` you can use still use `pre` tag no limit here and a little bit of `css` is required to have overflow property with the `div` tag.

In `xmp` tag you can place your `svg` code and then you can this `javascript` code so the user of your website can copy the code of your `svg`

```js
function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {
  if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.select().createTextRange();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }
}
```

```css
xmp {
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
  <button id="button1" onclick="CopyToClipboard('div1')">Click to copy</button>
  <div id="div1">
    <xmp><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-bell" fill="currentColor"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M8 16a2 2 0 0 0 2-2H6a2 2 0 0 0 2 2z" />
        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
          d="M8 1.918l-.797.161A4.002 4.002 0 0 0 4 6c0 .628-.134 2.197-.459 3.742-.16.767-.376 1.566-.663 2.258h10.244c-.287-.692-.502-1.49-.663-2.258C12.134 8.197 12 6.628 12 6a4.002 4.002 0 0 0-3.203-3.92L8 1.917zM14.22 12c.223.447.481.801.78 1H1c.299-.199.557-.553.78-1C2.68 10.2 3 6.88 3 6c0-2.42 1.72-4.44 4.005-4.901a1 1 0 1 1 1.99 0A5.002 5.002 0 0 1 13 6c0 .88.32 4.2 1.22 6z" />
</svg>
    </xmp>
  </div>
```